# Setting the content of TinyMCE Editor in Cypress and Typescript

Tags: typescript, tinymce, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am building a React Js application using Typescript. I am writing integration tests for my application using Cypress. I am also using Typescript for writing Cypress tests. I am now trying to set the content of the tiny MCE editor in the Cypress test. I am trying to use this library, https://github.com/ForeachOS/cypress-tinymce. But I cannot use that library with TypeScript as it is only for JavaScript. So I had a look at the underlying code that sets the value of the editor. It is as follow.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setTinyMceContent', (tinyMceId, content) => {
  cy.window().then((win) => {
    const editor = win.tinymce.editors[tinyMceId];
    editor.setContent(content);
  });
});
```

So I tried to create the TypeScript version of that command in my support/index.js file as follow.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('setTinyMceContent', (tinyMceId: string, content: any) => {
    cy.window().then((win) => {
        const editor = win.tinymce.editors[tinyMceId];
        editor.setContent(content);
    })
})
```

But it is complaining as follow.

```
Property 'tinymce' does not exist on type 'AUTWindow'.
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

If you take a look in `cypress.d.ts` there's a declaration for `AUTWindow`

```js
/**
  * Window type for Application Under Test(AUT)
*/
type AUTWindow = Window & typeof globalThis & ApplicationWindow
```

and underneath that is ApplicationWindow for **user-defined properties**

```js
/**
 * The interface for user-defined properties in Window object under test.
*/
interface ApplicationWindow { } // tslint:disable-line
```

You can add your own properties via declaration merging.

In your `/cypress/support/e2e.d.ts` (Cypress v10) or `/cypress/support/index.d.ts` (Cypress v9)

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    setTinyMceContent(tinyMceId: string, content: any): void
  }
}

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface ApplicationWindow { 
    tinymce: any
  } 
}
```

---

There's also [@types/tinymce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/tinymce) which may be useful down the line.

Comment: thanks it solve that runtime error. But the package itself is throwing another error. I will post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @JohnyDevNull, but in my case i had to do some changes

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getBySelector', (selector, timeout?, ...args) => {
    return cy.get(`[data-testid=${selector}]`, { timeout, ...args });
});

Cypress.Commands.add('setTinyMceContent', (selector, content) => {
    // wait for tinymce to be loaded
    cy.window().should('have.property', 'tinymce');
    // wait for the editor to be rendered
    cy.getBySelector(selector)
        .find('textarea')
        .as('editorTextarea')
        .should('exist');
    // set the content for the editor by its dynamic id
    cy.window().then((win) =>
        cy.get('@editorTextarea').then((element) => {
            const editorId = element.attr('id');
            const editorInstance = (win as any).tinymce.EditorManager.get().filter((editor) => editor.id === editorId)[0];
            editorInstance.setContent(content);
        })
    );
});
```

Also i prepared command for reading a value

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getTinyMceContent', (selector) => {
    // wait for tinymce to be loaded
    cy.window().should('have.property', 'tinymce');
    // wait for the editor to be rendered
    cy.getBySelector(selector)
        .find('textarea')
        .as('editorTextarea')
        .should('exist');
    // get the content of the editor by its dynamic id
    cy.window().then((win) =>
        cy.get('@editorTextarea').then((element) => {
            const editorId = element.attr('id');
            const editorInstance = (win as any).tinymce.EditorManager.get().filter((editor) => editor.id === editorId)[0];
            const content = editorInstance.getContent();
            return content;
        })
    );
});
```

in cypress steps then you can check value with:

```
cy.getTinyMceContent(<selector>).should('contain','abc');
```

Comment: I guess you missed the point of the question? It's about typescript error - how did you solve it?

Comment: I used (win as any).tinymce.... instead of win.tinymce..... and after that i added   '''declare namespace Cypress {
interface Chainable<Subject> {
tinymce: any;
}
}''' into declarations.d.ts

Answer (score -1):

Here a robust solution wich handles the dynamic editor ID's:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getBySelector', (selector, timeout?, ...args) => {
  return cy.get(`[data-spec=${selector}]`, { timeout }, ...args);
});

Cypress.Commands.add('setTinyMceContent', (selector, content) => {
  // wait for tinymce to be loaded
  cy.window().should('have.property', 'tinymce');
  // wait for the editor to be rendered
  cy.getBySelector(selector).find('editor textarea').as('editorTextarea').should('exist');
  // set the content for the editor by its dynamic id
  cy.window().then(win =>
    cy.get('@editorTextarea').then(element => {
      const editorId = element.attr('id');
      const editorInstance = (win as any).tinymce.EditorManager.get().filter(editor => editor.id === editorId)[0];
      editorInstance.setContent(content);
    }),
  );
});
```